# How to return plain text with react router

Tags: reactjs, router, m3u8

Well i have a simple react app using react-router to specify my application routes.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/video.m3u8" exact component={Video} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Well i need /video.m3u8 to return a text without any html tags for some reason.
Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean it's just a file? That shouldn't be handled by React at all.

Comment: Well that's a yes.

Comment: The idea is to get the m3u8 content from web socket and update it on request.

Comment: if i can handle it on client side of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, me and my colleague are convinced that this matter should be handled fully on server side (node.js).